# Calling Groovy script as a pre-commit hook on my subrepository using smartgit broken

Tags: git, groovy, githooks, smartgit

Calling a pre-commit groovy script independently elsewhere (not when located in my sub-repo) worked (using windows command line). I am using Windows 7.

But, calling a groovy script when it is located within a sub-repository fails with following error

> Caught: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further researching I found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7022

> invoking scripts using fullpath was broken

I was using Groovy 2.4.3, updating it to Groovy 2.4.4 fixed my issue :)